# Centos mysql access remote

Tags: mysql, ssh

I could before login with the username : username, and no password.
then it stopped working, created another account, so it worked for a while. Then it randomly stopped.

Now the users are ( from ssh)

[image]

i tired to login with the user root, omg, username  ( host %), and also tried on root and testacc on the ip adresses. but nothing works. ( i am 100% sure i was using the right passwords)

I get this while trying to connect with one of the users:

[image]

Q: How can i make this work? why wont it work out of suddenly? and could someone tell me more about how this acually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to GRANT access from outside in mysql.

1. Go to mysql server and login as `root` user.
2. Run `GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'81.167.51.107' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` for access from particular IP address or `GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` for any IP address.